# jquery - cant correctly pass checkbox object to function when 'changing' another input

Tags: jquery, function, checkbox, jquery-selectors, siblings

apologies for question title not making too much sense.

I am trying to pass the checkbox from the current row to another function where that function checks if it is checked or not and performs accordingly.

I have a table with several rows, and when changing an input `qty` I want the current row and checkbox name/id to be passed to another function.

you can see the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/c2dp9/1/)

The html in this fiddle is what is generated by my php page onload.

I can get the `onchange` to fire but the checkbox for that row is always `unchecked`. I think this is because 
`var cb = $(this).siblings('input[name^="treated"]');` is not passing the correct object to the next function.

I did get some assistance from @pXL previously with this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cmJu6/2/) but whilst it works in this example, cant get it to work with my generated html.

so when changing qty, I want `alert 1` to fire if the checkbox `treated` is checked for that specific row. if it is not checked then `alert 2`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var cb = $(this).siblings('input[name^="treated"]');
```

supposed to be

```
var cb = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name^="treated"]');
```

The `siblings` will not work in this case as `input[name^=treated]` is not a sibling of the quantity input.

Siblings are the elements are are present at the same level as the other elements.

But here the `treated` input in inside another `td` and not the same `td`

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c2dp9/2/)**

Comment: Okay, thanks for the explanation. awesome stuff. `breakthrough` :-) works 100%

Comment: @Smudger.. glad to have helped :)